# Accesory work to improve knee strength for squats

Tags: squats

I seem to have issues with my knee when I squat, could someone suggest me some exercises I could do to strengthen them for my squat?

Comment: Atg split squat with a slight incline at the heel. If you don’t have an accessory for it, you can do body weight Hindu squats ( squats with the heel elevated off the ground).                    Found these accidentally after meniscus surgery, and squating regularly felt like my knees were tearing. Found out what they were and how they help knee pain, and pretty soon I was able to work up to normal weighted squats with no pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Squats.

Just squat lighter, or do less reps per set, or less sets per session, or squat less days per week. Unless doing even bodyweight squats bothers your knee, you can still squat. And if doing body weight squats bothers your knee, it’s likely any other knee extension pattern will too. The idea here is that somewhere between doing nothing and what you’re doing now, the training dose became greater than what you were prepared for. Reduce the dose until you can tolerate it, and keep training.

For variations, there is nothing that uniquely prepares you to squat better than other exercises. Some of my favorite knee extension movements are the Bulgarian split squat and the classic leg press. The split squat is great for training control and balance, which may help your traditional squat if your control and balance are poor.